# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Getting database metadata caused by java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, hibernate

I'm trying to setup a database connection between my maven Java web project and MySQL database. I use the JBoss Hibernate tools in Eclipse. I created the following hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory name="">
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/mydatabase</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When I try to open the database scheme in Hibernate perspective in Eclipse I encounter the following error: `org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Getting database metadata` caused by `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused`.

I'm completely sure the URL, user and password are correct.

What could be the cause of this error?

Here is the complete error stack trace:

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Getting database metadata
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getMetaData(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.caseForSearch(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.JDBCMetaDataDialect.getTables(JDBCMetaDataDialect.java:22)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.processTables(JDBCReader.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.JDBCReader.readDatabaseSchema(JDBCReader.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter$2.execute(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.execute(ConsoleConfiguration.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.readDatabaseSchema(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.getChildren(LazyDatabaseSchemaWorkbenchAdapter.java:65)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.console.workbench.BasicWorkbenchAdapter.fetchDeferredChildren(BasicWorkbenchAdapter.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.ui.progress.DeferredTreeContentManager$1.run(DeferredTreeContentManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2209)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.libs.FakeDelegatingDriver.connect(FakeDelegatingDriver.java:42)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProvider.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getConnection(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.dialect.AbstractMetaDataDialect.getMetaData(AbstractMetaDataDialect.java:60)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:244)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
    ... 28 more
```

Comment: Have you checked out this question/answer? I see the comm link failure in your stacktrace as well... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983248/com-mysql-jdbc-exceptions-jdbc4-communicationsexception-communications-link-fai

Comment: did you change the default port of mysql?

Comment: @BlakeP I didn't check that one yet, however I tried all the provided solutions. I tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1, I restarted my MySQL server (running with MAMP). The other solutions I can rule out because I am able to connect to my db with a database GUI (Sequel Pro)..

Comment: @SparkOn I used 8889 which I guess is the default in MAMP. It is possible that I changed it a while ago but I cannot remember. I am sure though it is the port number where my database is running atm

Comment: This works for me after upgrading my jdbc driver jar dependency [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50914469/hibernate-tools-failing-to-get-index-info-from-postgres-tables)